# Fit LeafletJS map bounds while excluding outliers

Tags: leaflet

How do I compute map bounds/zoom of markers (each with lat/lng) while excluding outliers (e.g. from 10th to 90th quantile only by Y: most of my markers are in Europe and US, some are in Australia but for usability purpose I'm okay to keep them off the default zoom)?

Should I manually project first lat/lng to X/Y, then compute quantiles, then project back to lat/lng? Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

(If no need to exclude outliers, `map.fitBounds(L.latLngBounds(latlons))` works okay, but I'd like to exclude outliers)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to zoom and show a group of markers that can be done easely by using the `map.fitBounds()` method.

If you want to show only some of the markers you can put all the wanted markers in a `L.FeatureGroup`:

```
import * as L from 'Leaflet';
let pointsToGoToGroup = new L.FeatureGroup() 
//Add all the wanted markers
let bounds = pointsToGoToGroup.getBounds() //get the bounds
map.fitBounds(bounds) //zoom and show all the points in the group
```

you can also add options to `fitBounds()` to control the animation, duration, padding exc...

`L.FeatureGroup` docs: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup

`L.FitBoundsOptions` docs: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#fitbounds-options

Hope it helps, happy codding :)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any advice how to correctly filter the markers so that only 10%-90% quantiles in mercator projection are only taken?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, If my answer helped you I will appreciate that you vote for it, it helps a lot :)

Comment: For your question, there is no tool in leaflet that can do that action. However you can try implement it yourself. If I understood right you want to filter out the "farther" markers from the "center". You can do that by finding the center point and sort the markers by the distance from the center and remove X% of the point from the last. Hope it helps!